# How to validate if email sent

Tags: c#, .net, email, mailmessage

This is my code. I am using it to validate an email address.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Vishwaprani.ContextClass;
using Vishwaprani.Models;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;
namespace Vishwaprani.CustomValidator
{
    public class EmailAddresValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string mailadress = Convert.ToString(value);
                MailMessage email = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("emailvalidation123456@gmail.com", "Email validation"), new MailAddress(mailadress, "Validating email address"));
                email.Subject = "email validation";
                   email.Body = @"Test for validation";
                 var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com") ;
                client.Port=587;
                client.EnableSsl=true;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailvalidation123456", "U50h2#AP2XR@");
                try
                {
                     client.Send(email);
                }
                 catch(SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
                {
                     if(ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.GeneralFailure||ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.LocalErrorInProcessing||ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.ServiceNotAvailable||ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.TransactionFailed)
                     {
                         Thread.Sleep(5000);
                         try
                         {
                             client.Send(email);
                         }
                         catch(SmtpFailedRecipientException exc)
                         {
                             if (exc.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.GeneralFailure || exc.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.LocalErrorInProcessing || exc.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ServiceNotAvailable || exc.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.TransactionFailed)
                             {
                                 return new ValidationResult("There is a problem with your email address that can not be resolved. Please check it and try again later or enter another one.");
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     else if(ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.ExceededStorageAllocation||ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.InsufficientStorage)
                     {
                         return new ValidationResult("There is a storage issue with the email account. Please resolve that.");
                     }
                     else if(ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy)
                     {
                         Thread.Sleep(5000);
                         try
                         {
                             client.Send(email);
                         }
                         catch(SmtpFailedRecipientException exct)
                         {
                             if (exct.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy)
                             {
                                 return new ValidationResult("Mail box is busy two times try again later.");
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     else if(ex.StatusCode==SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
                     {
                         return new ValidationResult("Mail box is unavailable.");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         return new ValidationResult("There is an error with the email address you provided. Please check it.");
                     }
                }
                return ValidationResult.Success;
             }
            else return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I am sending the mail to a wrong email address the code does not throw `SmtpFailedRecipientException` and goes to validationresult. Success. Anyway I am quite new to this SmtpClient stuff. Does anyone know this how to resolve this? . This is the faulty email address I used for validation:

```
dffhgjwghxjgwjhxg@gjh3egxejh.comedkjk.
```

As you can see guys there is no way in the hell that kind of email address can be exist.

Proof (checked with my one):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
    address = new MailAddress("emailvalidation123456@gmail.com", "Email validation").Address;
} 
catch(FormatException) {
    //Invalid email address
}
```

[MailAdress.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.address(v=vs.110).aspx) property throws FormatException when you try to get it.

**Edit**

You cannot validate if an email address exists before send the email. You can use [SmtpClient.SendCompleted Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) to see the delivery status.

```
client.SendCompleted += new 
            SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);


private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
    String token = (string)e.UserState;

    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
    }
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
    }
    mailSent = true;
}
```

Comment: I want to find out whether that email address really exists. Think if you enter email address that seems correct but do not really exists. I want that kind of code.

Comment: You cannot validate if an email address exists before send the email. You can use SmtpClient.SendCompleted Event to see the delivery statu <== how to do it?

Comment: @user3762230: You could have checked the link. See the edit answer anyway.

Comment: are sure it is gonna work. I tried it . It did not work. ==>https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j_mRjMFFY6s0GOASkGfk4SmUTboBZkZipzvvqugLFL0/edit

Comment: @user3762230 : Read the msdn page in my answer

Comment: I checked with a real email address. that event did not hit. What am i doing wrong...https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fH2ue7PgUYxSwVsoin4uWV4F7AS4tccEliJ_7qJKr18/edit

Comment: @user3762230: If you follow msdn example in here it should work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Show me  the mistake I made here is the code==>https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EZSqeKkn8xPC0PhwsFvf8s9lr44KmBfpUeO0vpvUnuw/edit

Comment: Instead checking for boolean I checked for null values.